# perl: read and process a file in chunks

Tags: perl

I hope this question isn't too basic - I'm pretty unexperienced with
perl. My problem: I want to read and process a file in chunks, but the
delimiters of the chunks may vary. I have the entire file in a variable
$text. As an example:

```
One

Two

BEGIN

Three

Four

END

Five
```

I want to step through this file by chunks. I want to read until the next
empty line and save (and process) the result as one chunk, so "One" and
"Two" would be the first two chunks. If the new chunk begins with the
keyword "BEGIN," I want to read and process until the keyword "END," so the
chunk would be "Three \n Four." How would I do this in perl?

I have read about the "index" function, but couldn't make it step through
my $text.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set the input record seperator to an empty string to enable "paragraph" mode.  Then use the flip-flop operator to handle the range between BEGIN/END; something like:

```
perl -nle '$/="";if (/^BEGIN/../^END/) {print "> $_"} else {print "[ $_ ]"}' myfile
```

Comment: Thank you, the flip flop operator seems indeed like the thing I was looking for. My problem now is how do I break the loop at the end of the if statement? Because, as far as i understand, the else will return true forever?

Comment: The range operator returns true when the first expression is true.  This remains the case until the second expression is true which then causes the range operator to return false.  In the code snippet shown, additional BEGIN..END sequences would be handled just like you have seen.  If you use ?BEGIN?..?END? in lieu of /BEGIN/../END/ then only the first "BEGIN-END" block will be matched at all.

Comment: Yes, excuse me, you are absolutely right. I had tried to put your code into a perl script and run it on the entire file concatenated into one variable; it works with the diamond operator.